# Pyinstaller .exe not working, Failed to exexute script

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe

I tried to create an .exe file with pyinstaller but it crashes every time I run it and brings up a window that says

Fatal Error
Failed to exexute script

I tried to run it in command prompt to see if it would give me an error code but it came up blank before bring up the window mentioned above.

Does anyone know why I cant run this .exe or if there is a way I can get the error message when it crashes?
If its any help I am running windows 10 and the Anaconda distro of python, also used the pyinstaller commands in the Anaconda Prompt.

This is what it brings up on my PC

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcpSx.png)

The code I am using for the .exe file is the following

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import pandas as pd
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



##########generate filepath
'getcwd:      ', os.getcwd()
osfile, maindir =('__file__:    ', __file__)
mainpath = maindir.replace('Bell_Excel.py',"BulkFile.xlsx")




#########globals
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False,height=False,)
tfont = ("Courier", 10)
tbg = "black"
tfg = "green2"

#############generates window
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=475, width= 425)
canvas.pack()
backroundimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="tielvapor.png")
backround = tk.Label(canvas, image=backroundimage)
backround.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)



########generates frame
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
pilframeimage = Image.open("BellVirtual_Icon.png")
resized_pilframeimage = pilframeimage.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
frameimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_pilframeimage)
framelabel = tk.Label(frame, image=frameimage)
framelabel.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)







##########add file name button
bellfiles = []
labelnames = []

def add_file():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=[("Excel files", ".xlsx .xls")])
    bellfiles.append(filepath)
    path ,filename = os.path.split(filepath)
    filetag = tk.Label(frame, text=filename, bg=tbg, fg= tfg, font=tfont)
    filetag.config(font=("Courier", 10))
    filetag.pack()


add_file_button = Button(root, text="Choose Excel File", command=add_file, bg=tbg,fg=tfg,font=tfont)
add_file_button.place(relx=.33, rely=0, relwidth=.4, relheight=.08)






############# data processing button

def process_files():
    if bellfiles == '':
        return
    for file in bellfiles:
        excelframe = pd.read_excel(file)
        dataframes = [excelframe]
        compactframes = pd.concat(dataframes)
        compactframes.to_excel(mainpath)
        cleardata()

def cleardata():
    bellfiles.clear()
    labelnames.clear()
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        if widget != framelabel:
            widget.destroy()

add_file_button = Button(root, text="Process files", command=process_files, bg=tbg,fg=tfg,font=tfont)
add_file_button.place(relx=.25, rely=.92, relwidth=.5, relheight=.08)






#####Run app
def Run_Bell_Excel():
    root.mainloop()

Run_Bell_Excel()
```

EDIT: Game dev is a genius

Comment: Make sure that all the additional files such as images,audio,videos etc. that your file is using is in the same folder as of the ```.exe```

Comment: Ok, so should I move all of my dependecies to the dist folder thats created by pyinstaller or should I move the .exe to where all the files are

Comment: Either would work but I suggest to move the dependencies to the dist folder.